# Automatic approach for removing colord object shadow on white background?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am working on some leaf images using OpenCV (Java). The leaves are captured on a white paper and some has shadows like this one:

[image]

Of course, it's somehow the extreme case (there are milder shadows).

Now, I want to threshold the leaf and also remove the shadow (while reserving the leaf's details).

---

My current flow is this:

1) Converting to **HSV** and extracting the **Saturation** channel:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(colorMat, colorMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
ArrayList<Mat> channels = new ArrayList<Mat>();
Core.split(colorMat, channels);
satImg = channels.get(1);
```

2) De-noising (median) and applying adaptiveThreshold:

```
Imgproc.medianBlur(satImg , satImg , 11);
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(satImg , satImg , 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 401, -10);
```

And the result is this:

[image]

It looks OK, but the shadow is causing some anomalies along the left boundary. Also, I have this feeling that I am not using the white background to my benefit.

Now, I have 2 questions:
**1) How can I improve the result and get rid of the shadow?**

**2) Can I get good results without working on saturation channel?**. The reason I ask is that on most of my images, working on **L** channel (from **HLS**) gives way better results (apart from the shadow, of course).

---

**Update:** Using the **Hue** channel makes threshdolding better, but makes the shadow situation worse:

[image]

---

**Update2:** In some cases, the assumption that the shadow is darker than the leaf doesn't always hold. So, working on intensities won't help. I'm looking more toward a color channels approach.

Comment: Since the leaf is green and the background is white/shadow, you can work on the hue channel.

Comment: @GilLevi, see the update. It doesn't help in eliminating the shadow.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm really not sure. Perhaps using different color-space, such as LAB? Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: @GilLevi, no problem. What you're saying is essentially my question: which of these color spaces (LAB, XYZ, YCrCb,...) can help me in these scenarios.

Comment: @Mahm00d - do u mind sharing how you got this eventually ?

Comment: @Mahm00d Did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't use opencv, instead I was trying to use matlab image processing toolbox to extract the leaf. Hopefully opencv has all the processing functions for you.  Please see my result below. I did all the operations in your original image channel 3 and channel 1.

First I used your channel 3, threshold it with 100 (left top). Then I remove the regions on the border and regions with the pixel size smaller than 100, filling in the hole in the leaf, the result is shown in right top.

Next I used your channel 1, did the same thing as I did in channel 3, the result is shown in left bottom. Then I found out the connected regions (there are only two as you can see in the left bottom figure), remove the one with smaller area (shown in right bottom).

[image]

Suppose the right top image is I1, and the right bottom image is I, the leaf is extracted by implement `~I && I1`. The leaf is:

[image]

Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Really nice approach. Although, there are 2 problems with making this automatic: 1) I don't know the static threshold of the shadow, 2) There's no guaranty that the biggest part would be the shadow and not the other part (part of the leaf).

Comment: Thank you Mahm00d. The threshold in image processing is always tricky, that's why you may need to select the channels that separate the leaf and shadow with the largest intensity margin. And you may need several samples to roughly estimate the channels and the threshold. Regarding the connect components, the intensity of the root is much closer to shadow than the the leaf. That's why there are usually two connected part detected. Sometimes the root may carry some tiny parts in the leaf, yet the assumption that biggest part would be the shadow is true most times.

Comment: You're right about the tricky part. I have a sample with a leaf of dark green. In that case, it's almost impossible to find a static threshold that doesn't include parts of the leaf, too. Even worse, sometimes the leaf can be darker than the shadow! So, I think working on channels instead of intensities would be a better approach.

Comment: Instead of calling them channels 1 or 3, call them channel h or v?

Answer (score 2):

I tried two different things:
1. other thresholding on the saturation channel
2. try to find two contours: shadow and leaf

I use c++ so your code snippets will look a little different.

trying otsu-thresholding instead of adaptive thresholding:

```
cv::threshold(hsv_imgs,mask,0,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY|CV_THRESH_OTSU);
```

leading to following images (just OTSU thresholding on saturation channel):

[image] [image]

the other thing is computing gradient information (i used sobel, see oppenCV documentation), thresholding that and after an opening-operator I used `findContours` giving something like this, not useable yet (gradient contour approach):

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing with photos of butterflies, but with more uneven and unpredictable backgrounds such as [this](http://eol.org/data_objects/12530281). Once you've identified a good portion of the background (e.g. via thresholding, or as we do, flood filling from random points), what works well is to use the GrabCut algorithm to get all those bits you might miss on the initial pass. In python, assuming you still want to identify an initial area of background by thresholding on the saturation channel, try something like

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("leaf.jpg")
sat = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,1]
sat = cv2.medianBlur(sat, 11)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(sat , 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 401, 10);
cv2.imwrite("thresh.jpg", thresh)

h, w = img.shape[:2]
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
grabcut_mask = thresh/255*3 #background should be 0, probable foreground = 3 
cv2.grabCut(img, grabcut_mask,(0,0,w,h),bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
grabcut_mask = np.where((grabcut_mask ==2)|(grabcut_mask ==0),0,1).astype('uint8')

cv2.imwrite("GrabCut1.jpg", img*grabcut_mask[...,None])
```

This actually gets rid of the shadows for you in this case, because the edge of the shadow actually has high saturation levels, so is included in the grab cut deletion. (I would post images, but don't have enough reputation)

Usually, however, you can't trust shadows to be included in the background detection. In this case you probably want to compare areas in the image with colour of the now-known background using the *chromacity distortion* measure proposed by Horprasert et. al. (1999) in "A Statistical Approach for Real-time Robust Background Subtraction and Shadow Detection". This measure takes account of the fact that for desaturated colours, hue is not a relevant measure.

Note that the pdf of the preprint you find online has a mistake (no + signs) in equation 6. You can use the version re-quoted in [Rodriguez-Gomez et al (2012)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3279231/), equations 1 & 2. Or you can use my python code below:

```
def brightness_distortion(I, mu, sigma):
    return np.sum(I*mu/sigma**2, axis=-1) / np.sum((mu/sigma)**2, axis=-1)


def chromacity_distortion(I, mu, sigma):
    alpha = brightness_distortion(I, mu, sigma)[...,None]
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(((I - alpha * mu)/sigma)**2, axis=-1))
```

You can feed the known background mean & stdev as the last two parameters of the chromacity_distortion function, and the RGB pixel image as the first parameter, which should show you that the shadow is basically the same chromacity as the background, and very different from the leaf. In the code below, I've then thresholded on chromacity, and done another grabcut pass. This works to remove the shadow even if the first grabcut pass doesn't (e.g. if you originally thresholded on hue)

```
mean, stdev = cv2.meanStdDev(img, mask = 255-thresh)
mean = mean.ravel() #bizarrely, meanStdDev returns an array of size [3,1], not [3], so flatten it
stdev = stdev.ravel()
chrom = chromacity_distortion(img, mean, stdev)
chrom255 = cv2.normalize(chrom, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)[:,:,None]
cv2.imwrite("ChromacityDistortionFromBackground.jpg", chrom255)

thresh2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(chrom255 , 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 401, 10);
cv2.imwrite("thresh2.jpg", thresh2)

grabcut_mask[...] = 3
grabcut_mask[thresh==0] = 0 #where thresh == 0, definitely background, set to 0
grabcut_mask[np.logical_and(thresh == 255, thresh2 == 0)] = 2  #could try setting this to 2 or 0 
cv2.grabCut(img, grabcut_mask,(0,0,w,h),bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
grabcut_mask = np.where((grabcut_mask ==2)|(grabcut_mask ==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
cv2.imwrite("final_leaf.jpg", grabcut_mask[...,None]*img)
```

I'm afraid with the parameters I tried, this still removes the stalk, though. I think that's because GrabCut thinks that it looks a similar colour to the shadows. Let me know if you find a way to keep it.

Comment: Hello @user2667066, I was trying to test it; however, it is returning - NameError: name 'grabcut_mask' is not defined.

Comment: Oh, sorry looks like I forgot to define it. It's a while since I looked at this, but try something like `grabcut_mask = img[:].as_type(np.uint8)` (not tested)

Comment: I tried that, but it still returning me some error! I probably be missing something here.